# Drupal Migrate over SSH

Tags: 8, upgrading

I'm running a D8 site on a local WAMP server, and am trying to pull down my D7 database from Aquia using Drupal 8's migrate module in order to begin work on upgrading my site from D7 to D8.

I'm running in to issues with connectivity with my Drupal 7 database. The database is housed on the local host of Aquia, and I can access it using TCP/IP over ssh. The issue is that the Drupal 8 migrate module doesn't seem to support connecting over ssh. Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this? I did find someone else who was having a [similar issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2363659), but the responses were less than helpful.

Comment: You don't need the migrate module to do this for you, just open up a tunnel on the client machine and connect through that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server

Comment: If opening an ssh tunnel, should i just dump my d7 database directly into my d8 db?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the tunnel is to give you a connection to the MySQL instance on the Acquia machine, I wouldn't have thought it would affect your approach to the migration itself

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to understand what your saying. If I open a tunnel on my local machine, I'll be able to reference the Acquia databases as though they were on my local machine's local host?

Comment: Yep exactly right